# date() returning an empty string

Tags: php, date

I am using PHP's `date` function. The statement is as simple as

```
$t= 1339455660;
echo date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t); // not working
```

For some reason the above function returns an empty string:

```
" "
```

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

```
$t= 1339455660;
echo date('l, d F Y H:i:s'); // works returns desired result
echo date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t); // returns " " #wierd
```

Comment: Just tried it [here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and it returns `Monday, 11 June 2012 19:01:00`. Try doing just `echo date('l, d F Y H:i:s');`?

Comment: Working there but not in my prod environment... something wrong with the typesystem I guess, I am more from Strongly typed world...anything like typecasting...any workarounds?

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: so you're saying that that 2 lines (without anything else) script doesn't work in your production environment? PS: it has nothing to do with strong or weak typing, I'm sure it's about the reading logs habit (which is the same for both worlds) and debugging skills (which is the same in both worlds as well)

Comment: @sachleen: echo date('l, d F Y H:i:s'); works...but echo date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t); does not.

Comment: Works from the command line. What code is around this? Have you tried these 2 lines on their own page? Have you tried it in command line on production (e.g. `php mytestfile.php`) - What version of php do you have? (`php --version`)

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: `var_dump($t, date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t));` -- show us the exact output for this line

Comment: For casting $t as int you can use (int): `date("l d F", (int)$t);`

Comment: exact output of var_dump is an empty string ""

Comment: var_dump($t, date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t));  returns me an empty string...but my $t is as posted in the question itself.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: can you please copy-paste the **EXACT** output of `var_dump($t, date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t));` Just run and copy-paste, without adding or removing anything

Comment: logMessage('PAGENO '.$this -> PageNo().' INIT PERIOD ' . var_dump($this -> period[0], date('l, d F Y H:i:s',$this -> period[0])) . ' INIT DATE ' . date('l, d F Y H:i:s') . ' END PERIOD '. date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $this -> period[1]), 4) ....gives me the log message....:PAGENO 2 INIT PERIOD  INIT DATE
Monday, 11 June 2012 16:41:33 END PERIOD Monday, 11 June 2012 16:29:54

Comment: So? I don't see any empty strings but see the formatted date. PS: I asked `var_dump()` and only 1 variable and 1 expression - when you debug - you isolate your debugging code from another code, because it is easy to work with it (I'm sure you should know how to debug from strongly-typed world) PPS: http://php.net/var_dump - you cannot incorporate it into the string (it returns `void`)

Comment: What is `$this -> period[0]`? It returns an empty string when you use that. When you have `period[1]` it works fine.

Comment: It worked: just typecast $t to int... (int)$t

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: it couldn't be a reason. It is converted from whatever you pass automatically (but for some reason you don't want to figure out what's wrong with your code and use `var_dump()` but prefer to guess instead)

Comment: @sachleen: no you cannot know that. He uses `var_dump()` in strings concatenation

Comment: @zerkms...I did not even know how to var_dump...everybody please be patient with my lack of skills may those be debugging skills, php skills or communication skills...anyway..the integer typecasting has worked. Thank you everybody. I am still keen to know why integer typecasting is required here.

Comment: @powtac: could you please post your typecast comment as an answer?

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: it cannot be an answer. ".the integer typecasting has worked" --- it cannot. The date accepts strings as well as integers. " I am still keen to know why integer typecasting is required here. " --- it's not required, but if you used `var_dump()` we could help you figure out the **real** issue (but for some reason 30 minutes passed and you couldn't execute trivial code I gave you and copy-paste the result)

Comment: @everybody: I tried to give all information I had about this problem. Please calm down.

Comment: And it's the last time: `var_dump($t, date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t));` - if you execute **this exact code** and give us **the exact result** we could say what you're doing wrong. Please take the code as-is, doesn't add any other string and logging functions, and copy the output as-is, without any replacements or whatever

Comment: http://ideone.com/zFt2c --- here is an example of what to run and what to get as a result

Comment: @zerkms: I have used var_dump(), where to see its result?..my PHP framework is just a set of web services...so I cannot echo...I have logging framework which I use to print log strings...where am I supposed to view the results of var_dump() ?

Comment: @hrishikeshp19: in that case use your logging framework and log `'---' . print_r($t, true) . '---' . print_r(date('l, d F Y H:i:s', $t), true) . '---'` - only this exact expression (like http://ideone.com/PDk7s)

Comment: :PAGENO 2 INIT PERIODSimpleXMLEle
ment Object
(
    [0] => 1339460400
)
---END PERIOD 1339460994

Comment: @zerkms: got it..now I know what to do...I was supposed to parse xml first

Comment: What does XML have to do with your question?  Or, what in your question has anything to do with XML?

Comment: The reason why my date function was failing is I was passing xmlelement to date function...like...date("format",xmlelement)...which would fail. So, now I give the date function something it understands (which required xml parsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [typecast](http://php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) `$t` as integer using: `(int)$t`.

Comment: thanks powtac...that was helpful as a workaround, but I was making a fundamental mistake, if I correct that I wont require typecasting. Thanks to @zerkms as well for digging down upto root of it.

Comment: Why would you want to typecast, and how would it help, when `$t = 1339455660;` ?

Comment: @PeterAjtai Intuition. I wanted to force the questioner to make sure a useful value is given to date(). And it came out that that was very helpful!

Comment: @powtac - Well, yeah, it solves the OP's problem, but since the problem is not the same as the written question, this answer is not helpful for anyone trying to solve the question as written. In other words, I think your answer needs context (e.g. `while the question written as is does not need type casting, my guess is that...`)

Comment: Phu. Lots of word to write. Of course it was not the exact answer to the question (error), but since the example and the error explanation did not match I think it's ok to solve this question by this answer although or because the example in the Q was wrong.